# QNetworkReply network reply timeout helper

Tags: c++, networking, timeout, qt

Since Qt still does not support to set timeouts on `QNetworkRequest` objects, I wrote this little wrapper class:

```
/**
Usage:
new QReplyTimeout(yourReply, msec);

When the timeout is reached the given reply is closed if still running
*/
class QReplyTimeout : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  QReplyTimeout(QNetworkReply* reply, const int timeout) : QObject(reply) {
    Q_ASSERT(reply);
    if (reply) {
      QTimer::singleShot(timeout, this, SLOT(timeout()));
    }
  }

private slots:
  void timeout() {
    QNetworkReply* reply = static_cast<QNetworkReply*>(parent());
    if (reply->isRunning()) {
      reply->close();
    }
  }
};
```

You can use it in a very simple fire-and-forget manner:

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkAccessManger;
QNetworkReply* reply = networkAccessManger.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.com")));
new QReplyTimeout(r, 100);
```

If the call to Google does not finish in 100ms, it is aborted. And since the `QReplyTimeout` class is parented to the `QNetworkReply`, it will be destroyed automatically.

Review the code for any pitfalls, memory leaks, invalid casts and if it's generally in a good style.

Comment: class is quick and concise. I see no problems there.

Comment: I think this could only be used to shorten the timeout, not lengthen it. If you had a large file upload, I believe the internal Qt timeout would still trigger a `QNetworkReply.TimeoutError`

Answer (score 7):

Here are my thoughts:

1. It's a simple class that allocates quite a few times on the heap. You could minimize the number of implicit allocations it does. The `QTimer::singleShot` creates a temporary `QObject` instance and allocates a bunch on the heap. You can avoid it by handling a single-shot timer explicitly using `timerEvent`. You also avoid the need to set up any connections that way. A `QObject` does about two allocations when the first connection is added to it.
2. Use Qt-5 style connections, but that doesn't apply anymore in light of #1 above.
3. Add a static helper method that uses this class to set a timeout on a network request. The fact that you need to allocate `ReplyTimeout` is an implementation detail of sorts that could be abstracted out that way.
4. Check if the reply is running before you set a timeout on it. Perhaps it was an incorrect/impossible request at the moment it was submitted to the manager and it was immediately finished.
5. You're not supposed to name your classes with a `Q` prefix. It's reserved for Qt.

The code below is portable across Qt 4 and Qt 5:

```
class ReplyTimeout : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
public:
  ReplyTimeout(QNetworkReply* reply, const int timeout) : QObject(reply) {
    Q_ASSERT(reply);
    if (reply && reply->isRunning())
      m_timer.start(timeout, this);
  }
  static void set(QNetworkReply* reply, const int timeout) {
    new ReplyTimeout(reply, timeout);
  }
protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
    if (!m_timer.isActive() || ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId())
      return;
    auto reply = static_cast<QNetworkReply*>(parent());
    if (reply->isRunning())
      reply->close();
    m_timer.stop();
  }
};
```

Use:

```
QNetworkAccessManager networkAccessManger;
QNetworkReply* reply = 
  networkAccessManger.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("https://www.google.com")));
ReplyTimeout::set(reply, 100);
```

Comment: This looks great, but if the upload/download is large won't this timeout even though it's transmitting?  Should you cancel/restart the timer when uploadProgress is received?

Comment: @CaptRespect: I'd say that's outside the scope of responsibility of this class. It's the user's responsibility to specify a sensible timeout based on the knowledge about what exactly is being downloaded via the supplied `QNetworkReply`.

Comment: The `Q_OBJECT` macro is not required here and it hurts at least the compilation time (if not runtime weight of the object). Also, I would rename `timeout` to something like `timeoutMsec` so that it's immediately clear which units the timeout is in.

Comment: The `Q_OBJECT` macro is required on all `QObject`-derived classes. It is an implementation detail that it could be skipped on some classes, but it makes the classes thus "improved" not be `QObject`s in the Liskov Substitution Principle sense. E.g. all users of `QObject` expect that the metadata is correct and thus `qobject_cast` works. Skip `Q_OBJECT` and it's not true, thus you have a class that the compiler lets you use where a `QObject` can be used, but it's not really a `QObject` anymore. As for the timeout, it's Qt lingo for ms. If anything, I'd use `std::duration` instead.